# How to properly concat strings which contain user input

Tags: sql, mariadb, backend

I am having trouble deciding on how to concat strings of user input when I am fetching them from my db. Basically the problem is that I do not want to prevent users from using certain characters like ";" or "," The solution I came up with is making up crazy strings which I use as my separator f.ex. "-^-^;" I can be pretty sure that users won´t use them in that order and if they do the only thing which is messed up is the frontend. This feels pretty hacky so I am in search for a better solution.

```sql
# Wont be consumable by backend since there can be "," in user input
SELECT 
   id
   GROUP_CONCAT(my_entry.name SEPARATOR ",")
   FROM my_entry
   GROUP BY my_entry.id;

# This will work in 99% of cases but feels very hacky
SELECT 
   id
   GROUP_CONCAT(my_entry.name SEPARATOR "-^-^;^-^-^") AS names
   FROM my_entry
   GROUP BY my_entry.id;
```

In my backend I fetch the data and transform it to an array.

```js
let myData = await getDataForMyEntry()
myData.names = myData.names.split("-^-^;^-^-^")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a non-printable ascii character which is valid in unicode, but likely not used in any user input.

E.g. chr(8) = backspace

```
SELECT 
   id
   GROUP_CONCAT(my_entry.name SEPARATOR X'08') AS names
   FROM my_entry
   GROUP BY my_entry.id;
```

and extracting it with

```
myData.names = myData.names.split('\x08')
```